# Does PyEphem use the complete VSOP87 and ELP-2000/82 theory?

Tags: python, pyephem

Does PyEphem use the complete VSOP87 planetary theory and ELP-2000/82 lunar theory or a reduced version (such as given in Meeus)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference manual for XEphem](http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/help/xephem.html) (which [`pyephem` is based on](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/#welcome)), ["Credits" section](http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/help/xephem.html#mozTocId429783):

> The high precision planet positions were implemented for XEphem by
>   Michael Sternberg  based on the
>   papers
>
> - "Planetary Theories in rectangular and spherical variables: VSOP87 solution" by Bretagnon P., Francou G., in Astron. Astrophys. 202, 309
>     (1988), ftp://ftp.bdl.fr/pub/ephem/planets/vsop87/, and
> - "Representation of planetary ephemerides by frequency analysis. Application to the five outer planets" by Chapront J., Astron.
>     Astrophys. Suppl. Ser. 109, 181 (1995), ftp://adc.gsfc.nasa.gov/\
>     pub/adc/archives/journal_tables/A+AS/109/181.
>
> See the comments in chap25.h and vsop87.h for accuracy estimates.
>
> The high precision Moon code was also implemented for XEphem by Mr.
>   Sternberg based on code supplied by Stephen L. Moshier
>    at
>   ftp://ftp.std.com/pub/astronomy/selenog.zip. Mr. Sternberg also
>   incorporated the algorithm for deltaT, based on code also provided by
>   Mr. Moshier. See the comments in deltat.c for full references. My
>   greatest thanks to Messrs. Sternberg and Moshier for their generous
>   and kind assistance in making XEphem a program of first-class
>   accuracy.